# At Last, the Crown

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, music

[image: At Last, the Crown]

Clues:[contextual images]
[Fanta logo on treble clef]
[Winning slot machine]

Instructions: Name That Sith

_ _ I _ _ _ _ _

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'Sith' in question is...

> ...*not* an adherent of the Dark Side in *Star Wars* (as you might expect), but actually **[Cait Sith](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Cait_Sith_(Final_Fantasy_VII))**, the character from the video game [*Final Fantasy VII*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Fantasy_VII).
>
>  [image: Cait Sith artwork]
>  <sub>*Artwork by Tetsuya Nomura.*</sub>

There are several clues in the images:

> 1. 'At last' in the title connects with **Final**, while the Fanta logo in the image is in the position of the 'C' note on the musical stave, giving us 'Fanta C', or **Fantasy**.
>
>  2. The **crown** in both the title and the image reflects the fact that the character wears a crown as part of his usual outfit (see the image above).
>
>  3. The slot machine represents both the fact that Cait Sith is first encountered in the [Gold Saucer](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Gold_Saucer_(Final_Fantasy_VII)), an enormous amusement park and gambling spot, and the fact that one of his 'limit breaks' (i.e. special power-up moves) is called **[Slots](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Slots_(Final_Fantasy_VII))**, with a randomly selected outcome based on the spin of a slot machine.
>
>  4. The name satisfies the pattern provided - 8 letters, with third letter 'I'.

OP Edit:

> Additionally, the jackpot on a slot machine is activated with 7-7-7, pointing to the game being *Final Fantasy **7***.